# yii null foreign key

Tags: php, sql, yii, foreign-keys

I have such structure of db http://pikucha.ru/icFsc (I can't add pictures here)

Some addresses my not have a metro (other tables have the same problem, for example "user" may not have an address, but there is constraint in "user" table)

If I add a record in mysql it's ok. If I do the same thing using yii I get an error

`Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (address, CONSTRAINT    fk_Address_Area1 FOREIGN KEY (area_id) REFERENCES area (id) ON UPDATE NO ACTION)`

So, what's the problem in?

Comment: also showing your models rules will help you a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error can occur due to some reasons as mentioned below
1. Data Types may not be the same for fk and pk.
2. Size may not be the same of fk and pk
3. type may be different like unsigned, binary,unsigned binary and null
4. The value you are trying to put in city does not occur in area table

Comment: I checked each item. Unfortunately it didn't help. I allowed each column to be null but id. I don't have problem to execute sql query directly. But yii returns the error.

Comment: I have this. Or you need something else?
_UPDATE `address` SET `id`=:yp0,
`country_id`=:yp1, `area_id`=:yp2, `city_id`=:yp3, `metro_id`=:yp4,
`address`=:yp5 WHERE `seniordriver`.`address`.`id`='8'_

Comment: No actually i mean please post that code in which you are saving your model. Whether your are using yii assignment or custom assignment by using $_POST['attributeName'].

Comment: because if the query runs perfect in phpMyAdmin then it should also work in yii query. Because yii also translates the query and parameters to the query and parameters style compatible with mySql. There should be something wrong in your assignment. When you run direct query in PhpMyAdmin you check it exact values but when you run it through yii there sometimes exist unwanted values. You also need to check whether the values in the model are correct or not.

Comment: thank you for your help. I found what the problem was. Yii sent empty values as '' instead of NULL. I've added this `setOnEmpty'=>true, 'value'=>null` to rules and now it works as I supposed

Comment: ok, glad you have solved it, please change status of question to solved. and also add the solution you tried so the answer seeker may get help from this question.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you relation doesn't allow `NULL` values in the column. You have to edit the specific column, and check the `empty` checkbox. Then MySQL will allow `NULL` values.